# How to order different custom post type in category or tag template page?

Tags: custom-post-types, order

I have 3 differents custom post type : "Projet", "Notice" and "Disque".
I want them to appear in a specific order when they are listed in the *category* or the *tag* template page.
Like that :

## 1 - Notice

## 2 - Projet

## 3 - Disque

I've tried to catch te query string and use 3 different loops with WP_Query with no results.

```
<?php $my_notices_query = new WP_Query($query_string.'&post_type=notices&posts_per_page=1'); // only notices… ?> 
<?php while ($my_notices_query->have_posts()) : $my_notices_query->the_post(); ?>
```

the query allways show all the cpt with no restriction.
Thks for your help.
BR

Comment: I must say that I already add [this code](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/wordpress/make-archives-php-include-custom-post-types/#comment-164180) to make appear the cpt in my _tag_ and _category_ template page.

Answer (score 1):

someone [there](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/how-to-order-different-custom-post-type-in-category-or-tag-template-page?replies=5) help me and solved the problem.
It works. 
Cool.
Thks guys.

Details :
First - I remove this code from function.php

```
function namespace_add_custom_types( $query ) {
if( ( is_tag() || is_category() ) && empty( $query->query_vars['suppress_filters'] ) ) {
$query->set( 'post_type', array(
 'post', 'projets', 'disques', 'notices', 'main_menu', 'top_menu'
    ));
  return $query;
}
}
add_filter( 'pre_get_posts', 'namespace_add_custom_types' );
```

(I used this to get my custom post type in *category* and *tag* template pages. It also prevent nav menu to disappear. Here I don't need it anymore, I will use multiple loops.)

Second - Use this code in *category.php* and *tag.php* :

```
<?php 

    $current_cat = get_query_var('cat');
    // for tags use 'tag'
    // $current_tag = get_query_var('tag');

    // --- First Loop --- Notices
    $args = array(
      'cat' => $current_cat,
      //'tag' => $current_tag,
      'post_type' => 'notices',

    );

    $the_first_query = new WP_Query( $args );
    // The Loop
    while ( $the_first_query->have_posts() ) : $the_first_query->the_post();?>

        <?php the_title(); ?>
        <?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
        <?php the_excerpt(); ?>     

    <?php endwhile;
    // Reset Post Data
    wp_reset_postdata();
    // END --- First Loop --- 

    // --- Second Loop --- Projets
    $args = array(
      'cat' => $current_cat,
      // 'tag' => $current_tag,
      'post_type' => 'projets',

    );

    $the_second_query = new WP_Query( $args );
    // The Loop
    while ( $the_second_query->have_posts() ) : $the_second_query->the_post();?>

        <?php the_title(); ?>
        <?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
        <?php the_excerpt(); ?>

    <?php endwhile;
    // Reset Post Data
    wp_reset_postdata();
    // END --- Second Loop ---

    // --- Third Loop --- Disques
    $args = array(
      'cat' => $current_cat,
      // 'tag' => $current_tag,
      'post_type' => 'disques',

    );

    $the_third_query = new WP_Query( $args );
    // The Loop
    while ( $the_third_query->have_posts() ) : $the_third_query->the_post();?>

        <?php the_title(); ?>
        <?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
        <?php the_excerpt(); ?>

    <?php endwhile;
    // Reset Post Data
    wp_reset_postdata();
    // END --- Third Loop --- 
?>
```

The bad thing is that breaks pagination… but in my case, it's not important.
Thks to **keesiemeijer** from [wordpress.org Forums](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/how-to-order-different-custom-post-type-in-category-or-tag-template-page?replies=5) for original answer.

Comment: Welcome to WordPress Answers! [An answer should be more than just a link to an external site](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/faq#deletion). Please add a solution.

Comment: ok I will edit my answer…

Answer (score -2):

```
$args = array( 'post_type' => 'notices', 'posts_per_page' => 1 );
$loop = get_posts( $args );
while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); ?>

          <!--- YOUR STUFF ------>

<?php endwhile; ?>
<?php wp_reset_query(); ?>
```

Not sure if you're calling 'Notice' or 'Notices' either.... but either way you can repeat the process for the other 2 in your template file.

Comment: [Please read this in detail](http://www.slideshare.net/andrewnacin/you-dont-know-query-wordcamp-netherlands-2012). It will allow you to get around one big mistake. :)

Comment: I'm not sure.  I guess I understand that this is a second query aside from the main query.  So, instead, I should define the 'arguments' prior to `<?php get_header(); ?>`?  How would one do that 3 times like he is asking for in 1 template page then?

Comment: [Maybe you want to take a look at this diagram too](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/1755/385). It's easier to understand :)

Comment: Mmmmmmm.  So, use `get_posts()`?  I'm not the most familiar with this, and while I have certainly been humbled by the votes and your constructive advice, providing the correct answer would probably be the most beneficial to me... and the OP.  :)

Comment: Absolutely. It's a community thing and everything got an "edit" button :) And yes, it's `get_posts()`. Every other solution would be better done with filters.

Comment: Would you be so kind to write an answer that showcases this correctly then?

Comment: Just stuff your `$args` into `get_posts()` - give it a try and if nothing works, we can talk further.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/4414/discussion-between-rcneil-and-kaiser)

Comment: I'm in [the »Stoppress« Chatroom](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/6/stoppress) most of the time logged in. You can find me there, if I'm not away for a beer ;)

Comment: I'm glad to see that this subject is "hot".

Comment: I tested the `get_posts()` solution with no results.
My first solution is not working because it is just not filtering the custom post type as I want. To keep getting the wanted _tag_ or _category_ of the initial query, I must keep the `$query_string` in the new query… I think the better solution would be to filter and order that in `functions.php` but I don't know how. Thks